# Add tomorrow-theme to janus (macvim)

Tags: vim, themes, macvim

How do I add the tomorrow theme to Janus in MacVim?

https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme

What are the steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy the theme's `vim` folder into the `~/.janus` folder, as explained in the [Customization wiki page](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/wiki/Customization) of Janus. It would be a good idea to give the `vim` folder a more descriptive name e.g. `tomorrow-theme`.

For example, assuming you've got your local copy (clone) of *tomorrow-theme* at `<path_to_tomorrow_theme>`, you could do

```
$ cd ~/.janus
$ mkdir tomorrow-theme
$ cp -R <path_to_tomorrow_theme>/vim/ tomorrow-theme
```

Note the slash `/` at the end of the path to the `vim` folder.

Comment: To be more explicit, you need to add `colorscheme Tomorrow-Night` (or another themes that you have added to the `~/.janus`)

Answer (score 0):

Start by [reading the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_06.html#06.3).  After that, copy the files from [github/vim](https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme/tree/master/vim) into `~/.vim` directory.

Answer (score -1):

I guess there's multiple ways of doing this.

I `cd`'ed into:

```
.vim/janus/vim/colors
```

I created `tomorrow-theme` folder and `cd`'ed into that:

```
.vim/janus/vim/colors/tomorrow-theme
```

In the `tomorrow-theme` folder I create `colors` directory

```
.vim/janus/vim/colors/tomorrow-theme/colors
```

And that's where I paste the downloaded `.vim` themes

```
Tomorrow-Night-Blue.vim     Tomorrow-Night-Bright.vim   Tomorrow-Night-Eighties.vim Tomorrow-Night.vim          Tomorrow.vim
```

Comment: My understanding is that the .vim directory will get blown away every time you update janus, since it expects to completely own that directory. Ugo's answer is Janus's recommending approach.

Comment: Yes, Janus's page explicitly argues against modifying content in ~/.vim/.